# How to customise the zooming of Line Chart

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem. I am using the newest version of Xcode, Swift 5.1 and Charts danielgindi pod. I turned on the zooming of the LineChart and I want to customise this zooming. Here is a picture of the chart https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO4dN.jpg . I want the zooming to be only on the edges of the chart, not everywhere. What I mean, If the user zoom in the spot that is close to the bottom part, only to zoom into the edges of the line, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7YH4.jpg, only for the red areas. The same should be for the top part. Is there any way to do this.